# Does the dotnet command have an equivalent of Visual Studio's "AccelerateBuildsInVisualStudio" config value?

Tags: .net-core

The build acceleration feature was added to Visual Studio and described [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/vs-toolbox-accelerate-your-builds-of-sdk-style-net-projects/). I've added the `Directory.Build.props` file alongside my solution file, and it works as advertised...when building in Visual Studio I see logging output verifying that it's checking whether a rebuild is really needed.

However, I've since turned to using `dotnet watch` while working on a Blazor project. In the cases when hot reload isn't possible, dotnet watch will stop the process, rebuild, and restart the process. The rebuild step in this case seems to always rebuild all the projects even if they haven't changed, which takes a lot more time.

Does anyone know if `dotnet` is expected to respect the `AccelerateBuildsInVisualStudio` setting (I suspect not) or if there's a way to have `dotnet` skip unnecessary builds?

I'm running `dotnet` version 8.0.100.

I've looked for references of build acceleration in relation to dotnet, but all the results seem to point to only builds done by Visual Studio.